# Lenovo S110 netbook screen resolution Ubuntu

Tags: screen, resolution, ubuntu-netbook

I am still stuck with 800x600 resolution. Here is the output of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0bf2 (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0be2 (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at 86000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    I/O ports at 50d0 [size=8]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information <?>
    Capabilities: [90] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable-

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 390a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    Memory at 86100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel <?>
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link <?>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: 85000000-85ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-0000000080ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable+
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel <?>
    Capabilities: [180] Root Complex Link <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: 84000000-84ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000081000000-0000000081ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable+
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel <?>
    Capabilities: [180] Root Complex Link <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 02)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: 83000000-83ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000082000000-0000000082ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable+
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel <?>
    Capabilities: [180] Root Complex Link <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 50a0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at 86105000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2) (prog-if 01)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: [50] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information <?>

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    I/O ports at 50c8 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 50dc [size=4]
    I/O ports at 50c0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 50d8 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5020 [size=16]
    Memory at 86104000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [80] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable+
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3983
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Memory at 80004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Mask- TabSize=4
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting <?>
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-36-00-00-06-11
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8176 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 9196
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at 84000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting <?>
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-81-91-01
```

Also, I tried modifying /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf to fix this problem, but still does not work:

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Monitor0"
        VendorName  "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName   "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Screen0"
    Monitor     "Monitor0"       
        Device          "Card0"
             SubSection      "Display"
                Viewport        0 0
                Depth           1
                Modes           "1024x768"
             EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       4
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       8
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       15
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       16
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
            Viewport    0 0
            Depth       24
            Modes       "1024x768"
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier   "Card0"
   Driver   "vesa"
   VendorName   "Intel Corporation Device"
EndSection
```

I'm using Gnome. System > Preference > Monitor screen resolution sticks to 800x600. What am I going to do?

EDIT:

xrandr -q

```
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600         0.0*
```

Comment: Can you attach the output of `xrandr -q`?

Comment: @Samik: see edits.

Comment: you can check what video driver is in use by typing `lspci -v`, that provides more verbose output. can you update the o/p of `lspci` with `-v` option?

Comment: @Samik: I'm stuck here. What would be the video driver in this case?

Comment: no driver is currently in use, I think that's why the default `vesa` driver is kicking in and in your `xorg.conf` you have mentioned vesa as driver, one thing you can try, comment that line and open `grub.cfg` and in the menu entry add a line `insmod i915` and then add `i915.modeset=1` in the kernel line. then reboot. By this you will be loading Intel's i915 driver into kernel instead of vesa.

Comment: but before that, make sure `sudo modprobe i915` gives no error, then make sure `lsmod | grep i915` gives o/p `i915` and then do what is mentioned above.

Comment: modprobe i915 gives error and lsmod | grep i915 has no output.

Comment: Well, Intel graphics drivers generally gets auto-detected, however you can look into `synaptic package manager` to see if the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` is installed and in your case the chipset is 945GSE so it should be working fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
`xrandr -q` will gives the resolutions for your monitor and you can choose one by using `xrandr -s 1366x768` you can choose the resolution you want .

Comment: In my situation, does that mean I am eternally stuck at 800*600?

Comment: your issue seems different  you got proper VGA drivers installed ?

Comment: @NeigylR.Noval you can add new resolution with `xrandr --newmode modename modeline` then `xrandr --addmode modename` where you can get the modeline by `gtf width height refreshrate`

Comment: @Raja: I don't know what drivers to install on the first place. I have edited my question with lspci -v output.