# Cannot set resolution to 1024x600 properly

Tags: laptop, resolution

I've followed a guide to defining and setting custom resolution using xrandr, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Ubuntu sets it to 1024x768 automatically, but my monitor is 1024x600. The resolution is changed, but it seems to be lined up from the bottom, that is, the top part becomes unused. Here's the image: http://share.pho.to/979eD/ms/original

I'm using eMachines N214 netbook. The issue occurs on every version and environment I've tried: from 12.04 to 15.04, Xfce, Lxde (which is unusable) and Unity.

Answer (score 1):

[Their requirements page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) says that 1024x768 is the minimum resolution. It goes on to advise there is a netbook version which matches your resolution & Xubuntu and Lubuntu require 800x600

You seem smarter than I regarding things so I am just guessing you overlooked that or want to 'hack' a way to get it working. Best of luck

Cheers

Comment: Ugh, I've overlooked that one. But, in the Netbook section of the article, it says "since the release of ubuntu natty (11.04) the netbook version has been unified and is now part of the ubuntu-desktop edition, this has been done via the unity desktop software.", which should be able to support 1024x600. Couldn't get Xubuntu to work on 1024x600 either, even though it says it should support anything higher than 800x600 (1024>800, right?)

Comment: I just saw that. I imagine Ubuntu CAN support it, but you MAY be using the default GPU/video drivers that don't support that resolution & further there may NOT be any. I don't have anymore advice & I think they (stackexchange) are against linking, but maybe these ones will steer you in the right direction
http://askubuntu.com/q/148221/392305
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1953734

Comment: According to this ebay http://r.ebay.com/nhppm5 the N214=eM350-21G16ikk. Searches on processor & chipset confirm no graphics. Then found specs (sadly not in english, but close enough): http://www.emachines.it/ec/da/DK/content/model/LU.NAH0D.119
That confirms GPU/video-subsystem=Intel GMA 3150